Redirect to error page if domain name is changed in the URL using URL Rewrite Module
Need to redirect to error page when we change the domain name in URL.
My URL is http://www.xx.yyy.domain.com/Prod/search.aspx,  If I change URL to  http://www.xx.yyy.domainXXX.com/Prod/search.aspx
then it should be redirect to error page: http://www.xx.yyy.domain.com/Prod/Error.aspx
After changing domain name to domainXXX  in address bar am not getting error page,
Please let me know any thing did I miss to add in below code.


   <rule name="Redirect to error" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^xx\.yyy\.domain\.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://xx.yyy.domain.com/Prod/ErrorForm.aspx" />
            </rule>


